# How do I make a link open up the app if it's available?

Tags: ios, url, ios6

So I'm trying to figure out how youtube links work on a device. If you were to tap a youtube link in safari/anywhere it would open up the youtube app if it's available or just go to the video in safari. I'm trying to emulate this with my app.

I'm just confuse how to open a app with a valid web url. I understand that I can open a app with a url scheme such youtube:// but that not the same as www.youtube.com

Answer (score 0):

These apps implement what's called URL Schemes.

Here's a pretty good tutorial for setting up your own app with a URL scheme: http://www.idev101.com/code/Objective-C/custom_url_schemes.html